# .htacces redirect with exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with an redirect exception.
All the files in root were redirected to /
I want create a exception for the sitemap.xml.

My htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap.xml$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       site/web/website/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/web/website/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap.xml$
RewriteRule .* http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/web/website/$
RewriteRule .* http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But does not work :(.

Many thanks

Comment: What URL are you going to that is getting redirected that shouldn't?

Comment: the sitemap : http://www.website.com/sitemap.xml